# ttk styles not applying in python 2.7.18

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Hello guys [image] i m trying to apply ttk-styles with python 2.7.18 but it doesn't seem to work kindly assist me

```
import Tkinter
import ttk
import os
import tkMessageBox
from Tkinter import Tk
from ttkthemes import ThemedTk


window = ThemedTk(theme="Blue")

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you added any ttk widget to your window? Because the themes from ttkthemes only apply to ttk widgets, so not to the main window.

Comment: oh i have added didn't knew ttk themes only works on widget ..is there any way to change theme on main window ...

Comment: Yes, `window.configure(background='#0000FF')`.

Comment: thanks for the reply the one you told changes background colour , i wanted to know if there is some way i can change colour in title bar also ?

Comment: The titlebar is handled by the desktop environment, not tkinter so you cannot change it through tkinter.

Comment: ok thanks ...got it.. is there any way to make ui look a bit more modern in tkinter ?

Comment: Yes, to some extent, by using only ttk widgets and using the ttk theme of your liking or customizing one (you can change colors, reliefs ...). However, the comments here are not the place to discuss this. There are plenty of examples of this on the Internet.